# Is there a way to adjust the <select> @size attribute based on screen size using zurb-foundation

Tags: html, select, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm developing a web service that creates HTML  boxes in forms.  The server side (Django) template that generates one of these looks like this:

```
 <select name="typelist" size="{{ select_rows }}">
    {% for t in types %}
    <option>{{ t }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

I'm using Zurb Foundation to help me make the pages responsive to screen size.  I'd like to reduce the number of displayed `<select>` box rows when displayed on a small screen.

I can change the number of displayed rows by changing the value of the `size` attribute, but this doesn't help to make the form display responsive to screen size.

When working with Foundation, is there an easy way to set the `size` attribute value (or indeed any attribute) based on small/large screen size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guided by André's response, I figured a way to do it.  I'd appreciate comments for improvement.

1. Added some additional classes to the `<select>` box:

   ```
   <select name="typelist" size="{{ select_rows }}" class="small-size-4 medium-size-8">
       {% for t in types %}
       <option>{{ t }}</option>
       {% endfor %}
    </select>
   ```
2. Add some Javascript that uses the built-in Foundation media queries:

   ```
   /*
    * Adjust size attribute on elements with small-size-x, medium-size-x, etc class. 
    */
   $(window).resize(Foundation.lib_methods.throttle(function(){
       if (window.matchMedia(Foundation.media_queries['small']).matches){
           $(".small-size-4").attr("size", 4);
       };
       if (window.matchMedia(Foundation.media_queries['medium']).matches){
           $(".medium-size-8").attr("size", 8);
       };
   }, 30, true));
   ```

This is a minimal solution for my specific requirement, but I can imagine it can be generalized to handle a wider range of options.

This works with Foundation 5.0.3.  The latest version uses `Foundation.utils.throttle` - this appears to have been updated about 2014-02-20: see https://github.com/zurb/foundation/commit/ee5b3330b5908a787f5c1f22cdb2c630c3e14668.  The latest version also includes the `debounce` function that is not present in 5.0.3, which I think would avoid the delay in responding to changes, and allow a longer interval to be used without impacting the interaction quality.

Comment: As you've alluded to, you probably want to [debounce](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) your `resize` handler to avoid thrashing.

Comment: Done. I've edited my answer.  I note there are a number of recent changes in to Foundation in this area.

Answer (score 1):

Foundation doesn't facilitate this directly. For that matter you wouldn't be able to change the value of the `size` attribute with CSS Media Queries alone.

Most likely what you're after here is a JavaScript solution. Libraries such as [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) allow you to react to changes in screen size programmatically, which is what you'd need to do if you want to modify the DOM responsively.

**Edit**

Actually, Foundation 5 introduces [a utility for Media Queries](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript-utilities.html#media-queries) that may also work for you.

Comment: Thanks, this (in part) confirms what I suspected.I need to research the Javascript required to respond to current Foundation size selection (small/medium/large/...) - I guess I could do that with my own media queries, but I don't want to replicate Foundations own selection logic.